# do something if column number in 2 separate files have increased or decreased in value

Tags: awk

Please help guide me. I found some examples, but not quite what I needed.

basically I'm taking an output file with entries that have numerical values
and I want to do do something if the values go up or down..

for that I want to compare 2 separate files and if the value changed
(up or down) in the second column of each file then do something

```
File1.txt (reference file)

server1= 0
server2= 0
server3= 0

File2.txt (newer file)

server1= 2
server2= 0
server3= 0
```

How can I do something, if there's increase in column 2 of File2?
want to print "Server1= 2 has gone up"
Thinking might be done with awk?

i.e
server1 = 0 before and now it's 2  then do something

Also, want to do something if value went down

Example

```
File1.txt (reference file)

server1= 0
server2= 0
server3= 3

File2.txt (newer output file)

server1= 0
server2= 0
server3= 1
```

Do something else because server3 value went down

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show some attempt to solve the problem yourself. See [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This written and tested code did the task for me as far as what I understand from your question

```
awk -F"= " 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next }; ($1 in a) && ($2>a[$1]) {print $1, "goes up from "a[$1]" to "$2}; ($1 in a) && ($2<a[$1]) {print $1, "goes down from "a[$1]" to "$2}' File1.txt File2.txt
```

Can you try this awk code?

The output should be like

```
server1 goes up from 0 to 2
```

non one-liner version:

```
 awk -F"= " 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next };
($1 in a) && ($2>a[$1]) {print $1, "goes up from "a[$1]" to "$2};
($1 in a) && ($2<a[$1]) {print $1, "goes down from "a[$1]" to "$2}' 
File1.txt File2.txt
```

Comment: This is perfect Ahmet, Thank You!

Comment: You could make the 2nd part of that script more concise with less redundancy: `$2 != a[$1]{ print $1, "goes " ($2>a[$1] ? "up" : "down") " from "a[$1]" to "$2 }`.

Comment: @ahmet-said-akbulut How can this be changed to only output if the increment is 2 or more? in other words do nothing if increment or decrement is 1

Comment: Think I found the solution: ($2>a[$1]+1)